# Browser console showing null when fetching element by ID, but code executes properly?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, dom

I am trying to change an `id` of a form I have using JS. It works fine and changes the `id` when I inspect the HTML but the browser console outputs an error indicating that the element I'm trying to fetch by id is `null`. Why is the console behaving like this? Is it because I am constantly fetching and changing the `id` via JS?

`document.getElementById("myForm").id = "myFormAmended"`

Should I assign another attribute to the form to fetch it with? Thanks

EDIT: I have another function that waits when `myFormAmended` is hidden to change it back to `myForm`. After the form is hidden once and the `id` is once again `myForm` I try to execute the change again to `myFormAmended` and it succeeds but errors

Comment: When exactly do you see an error on the console? As posted your question is hard to understand because there's hardly any code.

Comment: I have a function that executes a GET request, but before it goes about doing that I have the line of code within that function as written in my question. As soon as it hits the line it outputs the error, but the line executes successfully and changes the required `id` when I observe the HTML via Inspector in Firefox

Comment: Changing the id of the element sound very strange. Are you sure you don't want to use classes instead? Or a data-attribute?

Comment: I use a single `<form>` to execute two different PUT requests. I have jquery listening for a submission from the `myForm` id and now I need to implement another jquery function that will listen to another submission from `myFormAmended` id. Thus, I need to change the Id to achieve my overall objective

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have executed this statement:

```
document.getElementById("myForm").id = "myFormAmended"
```

Your form has now the id of `'myFormAmended'` not `'myForm'`

So, next time you want to fetch the same form, you need to execute:

```
document.getElementById("myFormAmended");
```

And if you change it again, you should again query with the latest set `id`

Comment: This makes sense, I do however have another function that changes it back to original `id` when my form is hidden. So I guess my line does query the latest `id` in a way. I have an if statement that checks if `document.getElementById("myFormAmended") !=null` change it back to `myForm`

Comment: if you need to change your id for some purpose, first store the id value to a variable, then change the id, complete your task, and set the id to the stored variable again.